# Localization Angular 9 Medium size application

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, localization

We have developed an application in Angular 9 (Only English words), Now we need to support Spanish language as well. all labels and headings are defined in HTML pages.
is there any way Can I convert all pages to Spanish with out creating / reading constant files (entering all headings and labels in constant .ts or JSON file)

I see ngx-translate but I see it's using constant files and reading it. [(https://stackblitz.com/github/ngx-translate/example?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts)](https://stackblitz.com/github/ngx-translate/example?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts)

If I need to follow the same, I need to create each page (Our application has 100 pages approx) data in JSON and read from it.

Please suggest if there is any easy solution to convert or suggest best way to implement it.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: There is no easy solution, not sure how you would expect a tool to do this for you unless you build your own cli tool, since every application is different. Even then if you have 100 pages are you expecting to maintain another 100 pages for different language? Then you would need to figure out how to manage routing for languages. Just stick with what's proven to work and been used and tested by many other projects.

Comment: Thank  you Penleychan!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the best way would still be creating a json file for each language and read from it. it helps you extends more language, for example some day you need french, japness, hindy, chinese...

by the way ngx-translate seems outdated, there is also [transloco](https://github.com/ngneat/transloco), which works great

Comment: Thank you huantao , I will look at transloco.